# I am getting error in angular while installing dependencies of existing project

Tags: npm, angular-cli

```
    > grpc@1.16.0 install /home/soubhagya/Desktop/jobsterfrontend/Jobster/node_modules/grpc
    > node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library

    node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
    node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://node-precompiled-binaries.grpc.io/grpc/v1.16.0/node-v67-linux-x64-glibc.tar.gz
    node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for grpc@1.16.0 and node@11.8.0 (node-v67 ABI, glibc) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
    node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for grpc@1.16.0 and node@11.8.0 (node-v67 ABI, glibc) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
    node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error Connection closed while downloading tarball file
    make: Entering directory '/home/soubhagya/Desktop/jobsterfrontend/Jobster/node_modules/grpc/build'
    make: Entering directory '/home/soubhagya/Desktop/jobsterfrontend/Jobster/node_modules/grpc/build'
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/init.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/init.o
    rm: cannot remove './Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/init.o.d.raw': No such file or directory
    grpc.target.mk:470: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/init.o' failed
    make: *** [Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/init.o] Error 1
    make: Leaving directory '/home/soubhagya/Desktop/jobsterfrontend/Jobster/node_modules/grpc/build'
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/avl/avl.o
    gyp ERR! build error
    gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:197:13)
    gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:254:12)
    gyp ERR! System Linux 4.10.0-28-generic
    gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library" "--module=/home/soubhagya/Desktop/jobsterfrontend/Jobster/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v67-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node" "--module_name=grpc_node" "--module_path=/home/soubhagya/Desktop/jobsterfrontend/Jobster/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v67-linux-x64-glibc" "--napi_version=4" "--node_abi_napi=napi"
    gyp ERR! cwd /home/soubhagya/Desktop/jobsterfrontend/Jobster/node_modules/grpc
    gyp ERR! node -v v11.8.0
    gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
    gyp ERR! not ok
    node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
    node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=/home/soubhagya/Desktop/jobsterfrontend/Jobster/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v67-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=/home/soubhagya/Desktop/jobsterfrontend/Jobster/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v67-linux-x64-glibc --napi_version=4 --node_abi_napi=napi' (1)
    node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/soubhagya/Desktop/jobsterfrontend/Jobster/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
    node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:197:13)
    node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:978:16)
    node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:265:5)
    node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 4.10.0-28-generic
    node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/home/soubhagya/Desktop/jobsterfrontend/Jobster/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library"
    node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /home/soubhagya/Desktop/jobsterfrontend/Jobster/node_modules/grpc
    node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v11.8.0
    node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.10.3
    node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
    Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=/home/soubhagya/Desktop/jobsterfrontend/Jobster/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v67-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=/home/soubhagya/Desktop/jobsterfrontend/Jobster/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v67-linux-x64-glibc --napi_version=4 --node_abi_napi=napi' (1)
    make: *** No rule to make target 'Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/backoff/backoff.o', needed by 'Release/obj.target/libgrpc.a'.  Stop.
    make: Leaving directory '/home/soubhagya/Desktop/jobsterfrontend/Jobster/node_modules/grpc/build'
    gyp ERR! build error
    gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:197:13)
    gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:254:12)
    gyp ERR! System Linux 4.10.0-28-generic
    gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library" "--module=/home/soubhagya/Desktop/jobsterfrontend/Jobster/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v67-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node" "--module_name=grpc_node" "--module_path=/home/soubhagya/Desktop/jobsterfrontend/Jobster/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v67-linux-x64-glibc" "--napi_version=4" "--node_abi_napi=napi"
    gyp ERR! cwd /home/soubhagya/Desktop/jobsterfrontend/Jobster/node_modules/grpc
    gyp ERR! node -v v11.8.0
    gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
    gyp ERR! not ok
    npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/fsevents):
    npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno 1
    npm ERR! grpc@1.16.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Failed at the grpc@1.16.0 install script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     /home/soubhagya/.npm/_logs/2019-01-30T15_03_44_426Z-debug.log
    soubhagya@soubhagya-HP-240-G5-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop/jobsterfrontend/Jobster$
```

project version:

```
         _                      _                 ____ _     ___
        / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
       / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
      / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
     /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                    |___/


    Angular CLI: 6.1.5
    Node: 11.8.0
    OS: linux x64
    Angular: 6.1.10
    ... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
    ... http, language-service, platform-browser
    ... platform-browser-dynamic, router

    Package                           Version
    -----------------------------------------------------------
    @angular-devkit/architect         0.7.5
    @angular-devkit/build-angular     0.7.5
    @angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.7.5
    @angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.7.5
    @angular-devkit/core              0.7.5
    @angular-devkit/schematics        0.7.5
    @angular/cdk                      7.1.0
    @angular/cli                      6.1.5
    @angular/fire                     5.1.0
    @angular/material                 7.1.0
    @ngtools/webpack                  6.1.5
    @schematics/angular               0.7.5
    @schematics/update                0.7.5
    rxjs                              6.3.3
    typescript                        2.7.2
    webpack                           4.9.2
```

local system verion of cli:

```
    Your global Angular CLI version (6.1.5) is greater than your local
    version (6.0.1). The local Angular CLI version is used.

    To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false".

         _                      _                 ____ _     ___
        / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
       / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
      / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
     /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                    |___/


    Angular CLI: 6.0.1
    Node: 11.8.0
    OS: linux x64
    Angular: 
    ... 

    Package                      Version
    ------------------------------------------------------
    @angular-devkit/architect    0.6.1
    @angular-devkit/core         0.6.1
    @angular-devkit/schematics   0.6.1
    @angular/cli                 6.0.1
    @schematics/angular          0.6.1
    @schematics/update           0.6.1
    rxjs                         6.3.3
    typescript                   2.7.2
```

I am trying to run an existing angular project.
using npm install

But it is giving me above error while installing dependencies.

I have shared the version of angular for project and my system also please have a look.

The project was developed with 6.1.5 angular version

and i have 6.0.1 version on my local system..